# How getFeeForMessage for versioned transaction

Tags: web3.js, transaction

For legacy version of transactions I use transaction.getFeeForMessage, but for versionedTransactions I cannot call this method. How getFeeForMessage for versionedTransaction?

Comment: It hasn't been implemented yet, but https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/28996 aims to add support

Comment: What about non javascript solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible, as of `@solana/web3.js` version 1.67.2. Here is the [relevant code change](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/28996).